# Text in Textfield appears bottom of the text field, even after using .contentVerticalAlignment is .center. This is specific to iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

Took a text field and I want the text inside of it to be center aligned. Used .contentVerticalAligmnment = .center. In other parts of the app where this alignement is used (in storyboards) it works fine. If tested on iPad then the text is center aligned, only in iPhone text is seen at the bottom. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide more information and format your post please!

Comment: the text in black in image has to be in the center, not at the bottom of the textfield. as alignment is set to center.

Comment: It's working once I start using border style rounded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also occurs if your textfield height is too small. If you increase the height you will see your text right itself.